# Is "take care'n of" correct?

Tags: grammar, lyrics

Is this form of "take care'n of" correct in the following lyrics?

> She wanna be man cured
>  Ma-ma-ma-MANiCURE
>  She wan' be **take care'n** of

[MANiCURE by Lady Gaga]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After listening to the song I can confirm that this is an accurate transcription of the lyrics.

I can also confirm this is **not** proper English (not even in any vernacular form, slang, or any dialect I'm familiar with). Presumably the intended meaning is "she wants to be taken care of" [by a man]. I assume the songwriter moved the syllable from "tak**en**" to after "care" in order to improve the rhythm of the chorus, but doing so is quite an extravagant "artistic liberty."

Answer (score 3):

Usually this would not be considered to be correct, however, after checking several websites (I've not heard the song myself), they all list the lyrics as:

> Salon’s enough for her,
>   Not to feel so insecure,
>   Ma ma ma manicure,
>   She wanna be take care'n of

This doesn't make much sense from a grammatically correct perspective, and a more acceptable form would be.

> She wanna be taken care of

It's important to remember when such situations arise, in writing lyrics or works of fiction the author is entitled to a certain level of artistic interpretation.

Comment: Looks like there's quite a bit of word play, too, like going from "man cured" to "manicured"